# MongoDB match with $all ignore order of given items

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation

I have the following structure in the database:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6464acb09947e03e45b78b61"),
    "ProjectId": "64635ac02286d48c0c0d5907",
    "LabelValues": {
        "62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen",
        "62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
    },
    "KnowledgeItemId": ObjectId("6464acaf9947e03e45b78b60")
}
```

I want to write a query, that gets this element if I pass the two 'LabelValues' no matter in which order.

This aggregate works:

```
db.knowledgeItemRelation.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    LabelValues: { 
                        $all: [{"62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen", "62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen"}]
                    } 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

But when the two parameters are switched, it doesn't return a result:

```
db.knowledgeItemRelation.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    LabelValues: { 
                        $all: [{ "62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen", "62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen"}]
                    } 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

On `$all` operator there is no importance to the order by definition, but `$all` is for comparing arrays. You are comparing objects. When comparing objects there is no importance to the order of fields as well, regardless of the `$all` operator.
You can simply use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      LabelValues: {
        "62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen",
        "62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And get the document as the result.

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n6rc6rmYeZl)

Comment: But if I now switch the two LabelValues, there are still no results found: https://streamable.com/v7x2jq

Comment: Try it a few times, or once on a local db. It seems like an issue on the playground. When I click it few times it works. On a local db it works on each try...

Comment: Strange, on my local database it doesn't work too. Is there any other way to archive this behavior? https://streamable.com/ok4hf3

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trial and error and testing different approaches, I have now found one that works for me. I know that this approach does not have the best performance, but I still want to share it with you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "LabelValues.62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
        },
        {
          "LabelValues.62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
        },
        
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cNHx1iXKnRg

If you want to only match the given values in the $and filter you have to add a $count filter to ensure, no other results with containing this values and more come back:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "LabelValues.62d12558d75c134f54911490": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
        },
        {
          "LabelValues.62d12546d75c134f5491148f": "Nicht zuzuordnen"
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $objectToArray: "$LabelValues"
                }
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JJ2EY4-SsgR

Comment: The [query optimizer](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LXpJa-rxpEY) removes `"$or"` since it is unnecessary here ... so you may as well not include it yourself. `something OR nothing == something`

Comment: For a single and query you are right, this is not needed, however I have a use case with several and filters where the or is needed. I will change it or adjust the answer